# duplicate display of check Box VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker, duplicates, target

in the Range("J5:J1000, K5:K1000, L5:L1000 , M5:M1000, N5:N1000, O5:O1000") i applied a date Picker

i cant figure out why there is a duplicate display in cell O21 when i chose a field in the range.

it is stuck and i cant delete it.

the VBA code for the Date Picker is attached hereby:

```
 Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Dim openrange As Range
    Dim dates As Date
 


If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("J5:J1000, K5:K1000, L5:L1000 , M5:M1000, N5:N1000, O5:O1000")) Is Nothing) And (Target.Cells.Count = 1) Then
   
   
   With Sheets("SHEET1").DTPicker1
    
    .Top = Target.Top
    .Left = Target.Offset(0, 1).Left
   .Visible = True
   
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Target) Then Target = ""
    
    .LinkedCell = (Target.Address)
    .Value = Format(DTPicker1.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
   End With

End If
 

End Sub
```

[the problem you can see that i am on L22 but the display is also on O21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRdvA.png)

Comment: it dont work but the problem is related to this property.. it is stuck on the cell that was activeted during the opening of the workbook

Comment: I did not read carefully and did not see the attached picture. I cannot see any connection between the code we can see and the check boxes you show in the picture. Do you mean that only such a check box exists on that sheet and it is duplicated? If so, this cannot happen because of the code you show. Nothing from the code even contains a line related to any such a check box... It must be something else. Probably, another event triggered by changing, calculate etc.

Comment: Please, try placing a break point on the line `With Sheets("SHEET1").DTPicker1`, then run the code line by line pressing `F8` and see what other event(s), Sub(s) are triggered by the code you show. Minimize the VBE window and see what it does there...